# insert an object to an NSMutablearray of NSDictionary

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, nsarray

I am trying to insert an object to an array of NSDictionary but cant find out how. all the examples show how to insert to an array with NSDictionary with insertObject:atIndex, but this one doesnt insert the object under a dictionary key.

My array right now is the following:

```
NSArray *aaa = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Disable" ,nil];
NSDictionary *aaaDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:aaa forKey:@"Computers"];
NSArray *bbb = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Enable", nil];
NSDictionary *bbbDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:bbb forKey:@"Computers"];
NSArray *ccc = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Enable", nil];
NSDictionary *cccDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:ccc forKey:@"Computers"];

[listOfItems addObject:aaaDict];
[listOfItems addObject:bbbDict];
[listOfItems addObject:cccDict];
```

I would like to do this, but with a key "Computers":

```
   NSArray *ar = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"xxxx", @"yyyy", @"zzzz", nil];
    NSDictionary *arDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:ar forKey:@"Computers"];
    [listOfItems insertObject:ar atIndex:1];
```

Again - it does add the new array but not under the key "Computers". What am I missing here?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean?  What's not working?  `listOfItems`, which is presumably an `NSArray`, doesn't have any concept of keys (it's not a dictionary).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably wanted to write
`[listOfItems insertObject:arDict atIndex:1];`
instead of
`[listOfItems insertObject:ar atIndex:1];`

You're adding the array and not the dictionary like in the first part of your question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand exactly what you're trying to do, but did you mean to insert the ar object or the arDict object?  I think your code should look like

```
NSArray *ar = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"xxxx", @"yyyy", @"zzzz", nil];
NSDictionary *arDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:ar forKey:@"Computers"];
[listOfItems insertObject:arDict atIndex:1];
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean you want to add another array to a dictionary inside your listOfItems array? If that is the case it requires a nested method call as such:

```
[[listOfItems objectAtIndex:0] setObject:ar forKey:@"Computers"];
```

Answer (score 0):

When it adds the new object you have to get the NSDictionary first. So basically you are using the dictionary wrong. What you have done is equivalent to

`[listOfItems addObject:aaa];` and similarly bbb and ccc and ar

What you actually want to do is add the objects to a Dictionary and not a array.

```
NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[dictionary addObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Disable" ,nil] forKey:@"Key1"]; // your keys need to be unique
[dictionary addObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Enable", nil] forKey:@"Key2"];
[dictionary addObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Enable", nil] forKey:@"Key3"];

[dictionary addObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"xxxx", @"yyyy", @"zzzz", nil] forKey:@"Key4"];
```

Answer (score 0):

With leak fixed issue

```
NSArray *ar = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"xxxx", @"yyyy", @"zzzz", nil];
NSDictionary *arDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:ar forKey:@"Computers"];
[listOfItems insertObject:arDict atIndex:1];
[ar release]; // fixed the leak
[arDict release];  // fixed the leak
```